# how to force the request to always bring the zip code when placing the street name

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2, zipcode

I'm going through a probelam using Google Maps JavaScript API, without looking for the street name it brings the city and state, but not always brings the zip code, I needed that whenever I searched for the street name it necessarily brought the zip code also, the code is like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
         let searchAddress = document.getElementById('search-address');
         let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchAddress, {
            componentRestrictions: { country: 'br' },
         });

         autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place);

            let data = place;
            let addressComponents = data.address_components;

            let rua = '';
            let bairro = '';
            let cidade = '';
            let estado = '';
            let cep = '';

            for (const component of addressComponents) {
               const types = component.types;
               if (types.includes('route')) {
                  rua = component.long_name;
               } else if (types.includes('sublocality_level_1')) {
                  bairro = component.long_name;
               } else if (types.includes('administrative_area_level_2')) {
                  cidade = component.long_name;
               } else if (types.includes('administrative_area_level_1')) {
                  estado = component.short_name;
               } else if (types.includes('postal_code')) {
                  cep = component.long_name;
               }
            }

            console.log('Rua:', rua);
            console.log('Bairro:', bairro);
            console.log('Cidade:', cidade);
            console.log('Estado:', estado);
            console.log('CEP:', cep);
         });
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which area are you trying to fetch zip code. I'm assuming that you are aware that not all addresses in the world have zip codes, right?